# Has any equation with one unknown value a solution with complex numbers unless there's an indetermination or an impossible equality with numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

An equation like the mentioned has no solution in cases like the following:

$x+2=x+3$ That would mean that if there was a solution then $ 2=3$, which is absurd.

Also an equation like $x/0=2$ has no solution, as it is an indetermination.

But maybe for the rest of the cases, this is possible, for example the function $1^x=2$ has no solution, in real numbers, but does in complex numbers. I'd like to know if this happens for every possible equation with one unknown value except for the cases I'm saying it would be impossible.

As indetermination, I mean the one when calculation a limit of a function that would be related to the equation.

For example $1/x=0$, would have no solution.

But, precisely, the limit of $1/x$ when $x$ tends to infinity would be $0$, which would be related to the equation

Comment: for the case $1^x=2$, there is no solution, since that can be rewritten as $e^{xln(1)}=2$, or $e^{0x}=2$, so $0x=ln(2)$, which doesn't make sense

Comment: @sortai, it has, but in complex numbers, as I'm saying, check this: https://www.quora.com/How-can-one-solve-1-x-2

Comment: interesting, I hadn't seen something like that yet

Comment: Interesting question, but please clarify a bit more which equations are allowed. To motivate that, I upvote the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real or complex solution to the equation $e^x=0$.

Comment: yes, but this enters in the indetermination, as when the limit of e^x when x tend to minus infinity would be 0.

Comment: the absolute value of a complex number is given by the formula sqrt(a^2+b^2), and as a square root has two solutions one of them could be negative, so I think it wouldn't apply (althoug maybe it's not possible to consider the negative value).

Comment: That seems to be the answer, thanks.